# How to prevent Fedora from checking for updates?

Tags: fedora

The majority of the time when I connect my laptop or desktop (both Fedora 26 with Gnome 3.24) to a network, there is a large initial amount of traffic, usually between 80 MB and 120 MB. This is often, but not always, followed by a Gnome pop-up informing me that updates are available to install. This leads me to suspect that the traffic is from checking for updates.

How can I prevent this traffic from occurring? I frequently have Internet access only by tethering my phone to whichever computer, and this network usage wastes metered cellular data.

Somewhere I read to execute the following to prevent checking for updates:

```
sudo systemctl disable dnf-makecache.service
sudo systemctl disable dnf-makecache.timer
```

However this did not eliminate the issue.

Comment: Take a look at PackageKit. It's what Gnome Software uses to check for and download updates in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable as "normal" user, not root, su, or sudo:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.software download-updates false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a kludge and not a real solution; however, it solved my problem. If someone posts a better solution I will accept that. Since I do not know what programs on my machines are initiating the traffic, I decided to block the IP addresses they were connecting to.

These are the steps I took:

- Install [Wireshark](https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-install-wireshark-fedora/)
- In the menu for Wireshark under "View | Name Resolution", check "Resolve Network Addresses". This helps later on to find all IP addresses associated with a domain name.
- Successfully capture the unwanted network traffic with Wireshark, and note the domains that appear in the source and destination columns.
- For each domain, such as `example.com`, execute the command `host example.com`. This will list all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses that resolve to that domain name, and thus these are all the addresses that need to be blocked.
- For each IPv4 address `foo`, run as root `iptables -I INPUT -s foo -j DROP`.
- For each IPv6 address `bar`, run as root `ip6tables -I INPUT -s bar -j DROP`.

To unblock the addresses, run as root `iptables -D INPUT -s foo -j DROP` or `ip6tables -D INPUT -s bar -j DROP` if the address is an IPv6 address. Alternatively, simply reboot the machine to unblock the addresses - the effect of the iptables commands does not persist across reboots. I recommend collecting the commands to block and unblock the addresses into two shell scripts for convenience.

In my specific case, I found that my desktop was connecting to

```
admin.fedoraproject.org
wildcard.fedoraproject.org
dl.l.google.com
mirror.uoregon.edu
```

The first two domains appear to be used to select the best mirror of the Fedora repositories to connect to, the Google domain presumably is from checking for updates to Chrome, and the final domain, which was responsible for most of the traffic, is a [mirror](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist) of Fedora 26. This confirms my guess that the traffic was from checking for software updates. I have used this solution for a day thus far with success.