# How do I disable automatic check for updates in Fedora 32?

Tags: fedora, software-updates

I have Fedora 32 installed on a laptop which is relatively slow, and which sometimes has Internet connectivity only by tethering to my cell phone.  I would like to turn off the automatic check for updates that happens when I boot the system (and may or may not periodically happen while the system is running, I'm not sure if it does so or not).  The update check makes my laptop almost unusable while it's running.

I have already run `dconf-editor` and set the `org.gnome.software.download-updates` flag to "off".  And indeed, the actual updates are not being downloaded.  But - the check for updates is still being done, and package metadata is still being downloaded and updated (even though the actual packages themselves are not), and I still get the "Software Updates Available" notification after it's finished doing the check - I could swear that, in previous releases of Fedora, setting this dconf flag did have the desired effect, but now it doesn't seem to.

I've tried setting the `org.gnome.software.allow-updates` flag to be off too, but this seems to interfere with the ability to use the GNOME Software tool, as it seems like it causes that tool's metadata to never be updated (but that's just a guess, all I know for sure is that with that flag off, some parts of the Software tool work, and some parts just show me blank pages) - and it still doesn't see to change the "check for updates on boot" behavior.

I know other people have asked similar questions (such as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412604/how-to-prevent-fedora-from-checking-for-updates)), but the answers haven't been particularly satisfying (e.g., one of the answers in the previously linked questions suggests setting up iptables rules to block updates ... not exactly what I'm after ...).

Basically, what I am looking for is a way to ensure that nothing takes any action with regard to downloading package updates, or even checking to see if any package updates are available, unless I take some manual action to make it happen.  In general, that action would be me running "dnf update" from a shell prompt...  (And that's another reason this whole behavior is annoying - the times when I boot the machine intending to do a package update, run "dnf update" - and it fails, because the automatic update checker has a lock on the package metadata and I have to wait until it's done before I can do what I was trying to do...)

Comment: Try `systemctl disable dnf-makecache.timer`

Comment: Is the `PackageKit Daemon` running? Check `systemctl status packagekit`